# Chasing information about Marie Zierke

Tags: germany, marriage-records, death-records, photo

I am after information about her family details, any other chidren born to her, better a picture of Marie Luise Zierke (dob 27/07/1889.)

She married Willi Max Karl Babbel (dob 26/01/1891) on 22/05/1913 in Berlin/Spandau in Germany.

They had a son, who is my father, and Marie passed away not long after giving birth to my him. He is now in a nursing home here in Adelaide and while talking to him, he said that he has never seen a picture of his mum, his father remarried and Marie was never spoken of. Any help you could provide would be very welcome.

Comment: Welcome, could you please specify in more detail which information you are seeking? While the background information is fine the question is currently too broad to help you effectively. Are you searching for a picture? Or just evidence about the marriage and the ancestors of Marie-Luise?

There is an "edit" link to your question which you can use to change it.

Comment: Peter, I've removed the information identifying your living father, in line with this site's privacy policy (see https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3):

Family details:

The [marriage register entry](https://search.ancestry.de/cgi-bin/sse.dll?indiv=1&dbid=2957&h=188262042) can be found on Ancestry (registration required, paid subscription). As you already know she married the tailor Willi Max Karl Babbel (the third name was first incorrectly written Robert in the entry) on 1913-05-22 at the register office XI ([Gartenplatz 4/5](http://wiki-de.genealogy.net/Berliner_Standes%C3%A4mter)). Both were of Lutheran denomination. She was working as maid and was born at 1889-07-27 in [Kathkow](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/692621735) (formerly Bütow; today in Poland) and was living in the [Borsigstraße 12](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/1552045200). She was the daughter of the master smith Ludwig Zierke and his wife Berta nee Baumann - both living in [Kathkow](http://kathkow.kreis-buetow.de/) ([Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fkathkow.kreis-buetow.de%2F)).

The register entry also mentions that a son was born to them and that the birth was filed under number 740/1930 in the register office Charlottenburg II.

Regarding her birth entry [this page](http://landesarchiv-berlin.de/standesaemter-der-ehemaligen-deutschen-ostgebiete-neu) (not correctly working in Google Translate) mentions that entries are now at the State Archive of Berlin. Entries can be ordered with a form (see "Vordruck" on that page) [with a fee].

---

Other children:

1914 they were living at [Borsigstraße 12](https://digital.zlb.de/viewer/image/34115495_1914/4181/LOG_0283/). 1919 in Charlottenburg at [Spandauer Straße 27](https://digital.zlb.de/viewer/image/34115495_1919/5616/). 1921 in Tegel at [Schöneberger Straße 59](https://digital.zlb.de/viewer/image/34115495_1921/5738/LOG_0415/). 1924-1930 in Neukölln at [Innstraße 27](https://digital.zlb.de/viewer/image/34115495_1924/4031/LOG_0265/). (Haven't researched all the details.) Why is this important? Because the residence determined at which register office a potential birth was filed. Also it helps when you want to request a search in the "Einwohnermeldekartei" (residents register), which can be requested with [this form](http://landesarchiv-berlin.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Vordruck-EMK-Englisch.pdf).

Borsigstraße = register office Berlin XI (11),
Schöneberger Straße = register office Tegel,
Innstraße = register office Neukölln 1

When you know the register office then you can look into the name index on [this page](http://www.content.landesarchiv-berlin.de/labsa/show/index.php) ([Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.content.landesarchiv-berlin.de%2Flabsa%2Fshow%2Findex.php)).

---

Picture:

I don't think there might be a register of e.g. identity card photos somewhere. So the only way to obtain a potential photo seems to be to find other descendants of the Zierke family. The start for that would be researching siblings of Marie Luise and for that you might have to look into the birth registers at the State Archive of Berlin for Kathkow. What makes it a bit more difficult is that a lot of German residents fled the area with the end of WWII so it might be difficult to find out where they ended up.

---

Additional Info: There is a family tree existing on Ancestry containing Marie Luise Zierke maintained by a man similarly named like your father [the name was redacted from your question]. Maybe you know that already but maybe it is of interest for you.

(Disclaimer: I'm no Berlin expert. This is what I was able to research on the Internet. Corrections welcome.)

Comment: Marie passed away not long after giving birth to my father and she was never spoken about or anything of hers was keep in the house by his father, so this is why I was after a photo of her. Many thanks.